# A scene from the Disney story "Aladdin"

Tags: translation

> おろかもの！！！この洞窟に入れるのは、ぼろをきた心のきよらかなわかもの、ただひとりだ！

I need help in understanding what ぼろ means and the phrase/clause that follows.

I still haven't figured out what きよらかな is.

Also, I believe おろかもの means "fool" or "idiot". It must be extremely degrading to be called that in a real conversation, doesn't it?

Comment: Original English: "Know this. Only one may enter here. One whose worth lies far within. A diamond in the rough."  (obviously a bit different in Japanese)

Comment: You can search your words in a dictionary like jisho.org. You might want to look up 清｛きよ｝らか, 襤褸{ぼろ} and [愚か者]｛おろかもの｝. After gathering all the words' meaning you may try a translation to guess the underlying meaning of the sentence.

Comment: @snailplane Quite a bit different, really. Different enough that I'd be inclined to claim that you quoted the wrong line. (But I don't have either language version to actually verify the claim.) The English is full of metaphor but the Japanese has not a single word of it ...

Comment: @oals I am pretty sure snailplane quoted the right line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell

> おろかもの！！この洞窟に入れるのは、ぼろをきた心のきよらかなわかもの、ただひとりだ

quite literally means: "Fool!!!The only one who can enter this cave is a rag-wearing(ぼろをきた) and pure hearted(心 の 清らか) young man([若者]{わかもの})".

In the Japanese sentence, "can enter this cave"(この洞窟に入れるのは) and "only one"(ただ ひとりだ) are separated by said person's description(ぼろをきた心のきよらかなわかもの).

Answer (score 1):

おろかもの is very archaic so if someone uses it in a real conversation, it's almost certainly a joke. An elderly person might use it without the joke element, however.